# Incorrect End Date for event

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I've implemented a script in my google sheet that grabs gcal calendar info and displays it in various tabs of the sheet. However, the end date of each event as displayed in the sheet is one day LONGER than what is displayed in the calendar itself. Code below. Through logging, I can't figure out why its happening. Is there something to do with the formatting of the date? Any help would be appreciated!

```
function populateAllTabs() {
  var id = "[MY CAL ID HERE]";   // id is currently set to bookings calendar. NB: Takes a string!
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(id);
  var startPeriod = new Date('January 1, 2020');
  startPeriod.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  var endPeriod = new Date(startPeriod);
  endPeriod.setDate(endPeriod.getDate() + 365); // looks for all events in the range one year
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  for(var n in ss.getSheets()){// loop over all tabs in the spreadsheet
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[n];// look at every sheet in spreadsheet
    var name = sheet.getName();//get name

    if(name != 'List'){ 

        var gig = sheet.getRange(1,1);
        var gigName = gig.getValue();
        var events = cal.getEvents(startPeriod, endPeriod, {search:gigName});


        // find the title of each event in the calendar
        var eventTitles = [];
         for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) { 
           eventTitles.push([events[i].getTitle()]);    
         }

        // find the start date of each event in the calendar
       var starttime = [];
         for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) { 
           starttime.push([Utilities.formatDate(events[i].getStartTime(), "GMT", "MM/dd/yy")]);    
         }

        // find the end date of each event in the calendar
       var endtime = [];
         for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) { 
           endtime.push([Utilities.formatDate(events[i].getEndTime(), "GMT", "MM/dd/yy")]);    
         }

       var cell = sheet.getRange("B3");

       cell.setValue(starttime + ' - ' + endtime);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: getEndTime() and getStartTime() are Google Calendar methods:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#getEndTime()

I've also tried getAll DayEndDate() since they are all-day events, but still didn't solve the problem.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#getAllDayEndDate()

Comment: What about your spreadsheet time zone? You can verify it under File->Spreadsheet Settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me.   No problem with the dates

```
function populateAllTabs() {
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('id');
  var startyear=2019;
  var startPeriod = new Date(startyear,0,1);
  var endPeriod = new Date(startyear+1,1,1);
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var shts=ss.getSheets();
  for(var n=0;n<shts.length;n++){
    var sheet=shts[n];
    var name=sheet.getName();
    if(name!='List'){ 
      var gigName = sheet.getRange(1,1).getValue();
      var ev=cal.getEvents(startPeriod, endPeriod, {search:gigName});
      var gigs=[]
      for (var i=0;i< ev.length;i++) { 
        gigs.push([ev[i].getTitle(),Utilities.formatDate(new Date(ev[i].getStartTime()),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MM/dd/yy"),Utilities.formatDate(new Date(ev[i].getEndTime()),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MM/dd/yy")]);    
      }
      if(gigs) {
        sheet.getRange(3,2,gigs.length,gigs[0].length).setValues(gigs);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't seem to solve it. Using the getTimeZone() and doing some logging, the start and end times are both Central Standard time. This is what they should be. However, the calendar has events that end on Jan 20th that appear in my spreadsheet as Jan 21, and same for all the other events I'm trying to display!

Comment: What is the timezone of the spreadsheet?The script and the spreadsheet have separate timezone settings.

Comment: I setup a test and modified the code a bit and I can confirm that it works for me.

Comment: Man, OK I solved it. Totally unrelated to the code. The first tab in the sheet is an index, and my co-worker had made that index populate the tabs I've been trying to manipulate. :/ THANK YOU for your help!

Comment: I added the test to check if there were gigs before trying to write to the sheet.  I didn't catch that because in my example I had it set up to always find something in  each sheet.